# When rotating reference frames using the XYZ fixed angle convention, why do we multiply matrices in the inverse order that rotation was done?

Tags: linear-transformations, rotations, robotics

I'm reading about the XYZ fixed angle convention for relating reference frames. It says that to solve for the description of frame {B} in frame {A} we do the following:

> Start with the frame coincident with a known reference frame {A}. Rotate
> {B} first about $X_A$ by an angle $\gamma$ , then about $Y_A$ by an angle $\beta$, and, finally, about $Z_A$ by an angle $\alpha$.

Conceptually, why do we multiply in the order $R_Z(\alpha)R_Y(\beta)R_X(\gamma)$ when the actual rotation occurred in the reverse order?

[Drawing of each step in the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRTqY.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your conventions on how a matrix $A$ acts on a vector $v$. Does the matrix act on the left ($Av$) or the right ($vA$)? This is essentially a question of whether you think of the vectors as row vectors or column vectors.

If the matrix acts on the left, then $AB$ would act as $ABv$. As you can see, with this convention, $B$ acts on $v$ first, then $A$.  So $AB$ means do $B$, then $A$.

If the matrix acts on the right, then $AB$ would act as $vAB$. With this alternate convention, $A$ acts first, then $B$.  So $AB$ means do $A$, then $B$.

Either convention is fine. But you have to be consistent throughout, or the calculations will be wrong.